# AsyncContext ReadListener still running after timeout

Tags: java, servlets, jetty

I'm trying to stop an AsyncContext in two cases (request timeout, a request has been canceled). I set the timeout for the context but after the onTimeout event raised, it seems that the ReadListener was still running. How can I stop it? I noticed that the program threw `java.lang.IllegalStateException: s=ASYNC_IO i=false a=EXPIRED`, that means the context has been completed, (at least if not, when I called context.complete() in the onTimeout, the same exception raised). I don't want ReadListener to still run after timeout, how can I do it. tks

Comment: What version of Jetty?

Comment: @Joakim Erdfelt jetty 9.3.9

Comment: That's quite old.  Can you try again with Jetty 9.4.14? (lots of bug fixes you are missing)

Comment: @Joakim Erdfelt I cannot switch to any newer versions, unfortunately :(.

Comment: There's literally over 1,000 bug fixes (and 4,364 commits) between 9.3.9 and 9.4.14 (several hundred around AsyncContext alone).  Also the entire 9.3.x series is in security maintenance mode right now (no more bug fixes).  Jetty 9.4.x is current stable, Jetty 10.x is where most development is happening.

Comment: @Joakim Erdfelt ok thanks. let me see if it could solve the problem.